# Batch file on flash drive - how to check OS architecture?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm setting up a portable development environment.  I'm trying to get the bitness of the current system my flash drive is plugged into (32 or 64) from a batch file, so I can use the correct version of my IDE.

This article is a start: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556009 but it uses a relative address, and of course my flash drive doesn't have an OS so the code defaults to i586 every time.

What's the LOC I need to do this?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I don't see anything in that article that cares about where the batch file lives. Looks to me like it just executes a registry query and reads the results. What part are you referring to about the relative address?

Comment: I was looking at `HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0` and guessing that's the problem, but apparently my terminology is wrong...either way, when used on a flash drive, that code returns 32 bit on a 64 bit system.

Comment: I just looked at this particular registry key on my machine, and it shows 0x00000080 (128), so apparently I'm running Windows XP 128-bit. Either that, or the article is wrong (I'd bet on that one...)

Comment: You say it's support.microsoft.com? My god man they're infallible!  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a caveat to Tobias Schlegel's solution:  The PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable only returns the bitness of the current process.  On a 64-bit machine, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE will still be "x86" in 32-bit processes, due to WoW64 emulation.

To remedy this, Microsoft added a new environment variable, PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432, which is only defined in processes running under WoW64.

The correct code is therefore:

```
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" == "x86" if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%" == "" goto Arch32
goto Arch64

:Arch32
echo System architecture is 32-bit!
goto:eof

:Arch64
echo System architecture is 64-bit!
goto:eof
```

This distinction is important because if you launch cmd.exe from a 32-bit process on a 64-bit machine, then cmd.exe will be running under WoW64, and the accepted solution would therefore be incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

just check the PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE environment variable on my 64-bit machine it's "AMD64", i guess on a 32bit machine it's "x86".

Answer (score 1):

`wmic OS get OSArchitecture`

Should return either `32-bit` or `64-bit`.

Comment: I get `Invalid query` running that. When I run `wmic` and call `OS` manually, I see a bunch of system stuff, but nothing on the bitness, except maybe `CreationClassName=Win32_OperatingSystem` and `CSCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem`, but that doesn't seem official to me.

Comment: Interesting.  What version are you on?  The `Win32_OperatingSystem` stuff is not relevant; it is on both 32 and 64-bit machines.  If you're on 64-bit, try `wmic OS | findstr 64` or `findstr \-bit` and see if there's any indication that it contains the string `64-bit` or `32-bit`.

Comment: Also, are you actually running this from command prompt or are you using powershell or similar?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that - XP professional 32-bit, from cmd.exe. I just tried on my Windows 7 (Ultimate x86) machine, and I am getting `32-bit` here, so maybe it's new with Win7 or maybe Vista. I don't have a 64-bit machine around, so I can't try that.

Comment: Hmm interesting; I thought this was XP-compat, but I've only ever tried it on 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can this piece of code (registry):

```
Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0

REG.exe Query %RegQry% 2>NUL | find /I /N "x86">NUL

If [%ERRORLEVEL%] == [0] (
    echo X86
) ELSE (
    echo AMD64
)
```