# I need advise on batch file code

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a newbee batch file coding question
I need to check the OS on the machine: it is windows always:
and determine if it is 32 or 64 bit.
and then 
     if (32) {
so something 
 and if 64 do soemthing else
how do i do it in batch file:
I found this command: 
       wmic OS get OSArchitecture.
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004446/batch-file-on-flash-drive-how-to-check-os-architecture)